# Help! Wordpress posts returning 404 (Debian + Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, wordpress, debian-lenny

Index loads. Search works and loads posts (meaning the DB is fine).

I just transferred to a new server. HELP!

Comment: It's not a plugin issue.

I'm sorry, but I'm new to this all. How do I pull up Apache logs?

Comment: Hey Evan: just for future reference on the site, use the Add Comment function underneath questions and answers instead of posting a new answer every time you need to reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Just post your root password and I'll connect to the machine and we'll fix it for you!

Note for the humor/common sense impaired: do NOT really do that!

Answer (score 1):

Change your Permalinks back to Default.
Now do links work?

Have you visited the [Using_Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) page in the WordPress codex? Lots of trouble-shooting tips.

Added:

In particular, confirm with your host that mod_rewrite and AllowOverride are both on and enabled. (peek in your httpd.conf)

Comment: Thanks Chris_K! It works on Default, but how do I return to the structure of my choosing?

Comment: I think that's the problem.

httpd.conf is blank

pardon my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache logs and give us some info.

Until then this question is of a type: "It doesn't work. Get me an answer why from a crystal ball"

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that happen with poorly written plugins installed.  You could try disabling some plugins and see if things start working and if so then put them back one by one.

Before disabling them you could also go through all of the configs and see if any are set to reference old host names / IP's whatever. (if your new machine is different from the original...)